# PrimeNG multiselect filter for table showing empty message always

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have the following implementation for multi select filter for the prime ng table

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="environments" (onChange)="onMultiselect($event)" optionLabel="environment_id">
<ng-template let-option pTemplate="item">
    <div class="p-multiselect-representative-option">
        <span class="p-ml-1">{{option.label}}</span>
    </div>
</ng-template>
</p-multiSelect>
```

and in the `.ts` file I have:

```
this.environments = [
    {
        environment_id:"BVT"
    },
    {
        environment_id:"UAT"
    }
];

public onMultiselect(event)
{
    this.table.filter(event.value, 'environment_id', 'in');
}
```

The filter is showing correctly and showing both the environments I have specified. But when I select them for searching, the table is showing the empty message. I have corresponding values in the table, but it is not showing those values. How can I solve this ?

I am getting the `event.value` correctly as the array of objects that is specified.